# after changing my flutter channel from beta to stable , error started coming up

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I moved to stable flutter channel from beta, after upgrading flutter,

I am getting error for ListTile() attributes and ScaffoldMassanger,

```
 child: ListTile(
        horizontalTitleGap: 10, // error
        minVerticalPadding: 10, // error
        ),


  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text('success'),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
  ));
```

I tried below solutions:

```
 flutter upgrade
 flutter clean
 flutter pub get
 reinstalled dart and flutter plugin in VSCode
 flutter run
 updated vscode
```

no success

error log after removing depreciated attributes,

lib/widgets/list_expense.dart:32:9: Error: The getter 'ScaffoldMessenger' isn't defined for the class '_ListExpenseState'.

- '_ListExpenseState' is from 'package:XpenseTracker/widgets/list_expense.dart' ('lib/widgets/list_expense.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'ScaffoldMessenger'.
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(

Comment: Do flutter clean, and then run

Comment: Can you also share the errors you are getting?

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede, I tried flutter clean and run , getting same

Comment: These properties will have been deprecated and then removed. You should try to use an alternative. Also yes, please copy the error in this post or we can't be sure.

Comment: I have replaced the attributes, but I am getting error for Scaffold Massanger, and added error by editing , please have a look for Scaffold massanger

Comment: @gkpln3, yes I have edited my post and added error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties have been removed, as can be seen in the class (**ListTile**) documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile/ListTile.html

Please take a look at this package here, in order to use these properties:
https://pub.dev/packages/list_tile_more_customizable

[**EDIT**]
For your Scaffold issue please try to use a static helper function like so, then pass the string to render, along with the **BuildContext**:

```
 static Future showSimpleSnackBar(
      String message, GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> contextState) async {
      final snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text(message),
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        action: SnackBarAction(
          label: "Got it",
          onPressed: () {
            //invoke an action here...
          },
        ),
      );

  contextState.currentState.removeCurrentSnackBar(); 
  contextState.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
```

Make sure as well that the **BuildContext** is coming from a **Global ScaffoldKey**, and that the scaffold will be responsible with rendering the snackbar.

Comment: got it , its been depreciated, but can I know the issue with ScaffoldMassanger , it's a new update for snackbar

Comment: I tried implementing your solution , now I am getting error for,

currentContext.removeCurrentSnackBar(); //error
currentContext.showSnackBar(snackBar); //error

Comment: Sorry, the bug was on my end. Please review my answer now. And make sure that you pass a ScaffoldKey into the method.

Comment: I am using a BottomNavigationBar , and a showModalBottomSheet , and I need to show SnackBar once showModalBottomSheet is poped, so my Scaffold Key to snakbar should be from main scaffold where I have implemented BottomNavigationBar  right?

Comment: yes, correct. The same scaffold key that you are using to get the BuildContext, to render the bottom sheet, has to be used to render the snackbar. You must make sure that the bottom sheet has completely disappeared before rendering the snackbar, otherwise the snackbar will be rendered below the bottom sheet, which kind of misses the point.

Comment: That was deprecated, not depreciated.  Yes, they definitely mean very different things :)